# How to import R programming language into IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: r, intellij

I'm using Kubuntu 20.10. I have installed Intellij IDEA without any problems; but I can't install R into it. I can install other programming languages such as Kotlin, Java or Python; but not R. And I can use R in RStudio; so it is installed correctly.

Could you please help?
What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6632-r-language-for-intellij ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply; but the problem is that I have already installed that plug-in. The IDE does not recognize R.exe